# How to change the background color of a sql view based on the column values?

Tags: php, html

```
    echo "<td bgcolor='#d5eaf0'>{$row[0]}</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor='#d5eaf0'>{$row[1]}</td>";
  //echo "<td>{$row[2]}</td>";
    if ($row[2]=0)
    echo "<td bgcolor='green'>{$row[2]}</td>";
    else if ($row[2]>0)
    echo "<td bgcolor='red'>{$row[2]}</td>";
```

In row[2] I want red colour if column value > 0.
In row[2] I want green colour if column value = 0.
Above query is not working. Please help me out here.

Comment: add if ($row[2]==0) not if ($row[2]=0)

Comment: if should be if `($row[2]==0)`  `(==)` you have used one equal sign

Comment: you are assigning value, the way you doing like this $row[2]=0, if you want check the value use like this $row[2]==0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '==' inside if()

```
if ($row[2]==0)
```

Comment: Thank you all. Appreciate for your time.

Comment: Please upvote the answers and select one as the answer, if that helped you.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<td bgcolor='#d5eaf0'>{$row[0]}</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor='#d5eaf0'>{$row[1]}</td>";
  //echo "<td>{$row[2]}</td>";
    if ($row[2]==0)
    echo "<td bgcolor='green'>{$row[2]}</td>";
    else if ($row[2]>0)
    echo "<td bgcolor='red'>{$row[2]}</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `=` which is assignment operator instead of using comparison operator `==`.

```
if ($row[2]==0)
  echo "<td bgcolor='green'>{$row[2]}</td>";
else if ($row[2]>0)
  echo "<td bgcolor='red'>{$row[2]}</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`if ($row[2]=0)` boils always down to `if(true)` because one `=` means you assign something.

Try `if ($row[2]==0)`